# How connect to remote machine by private key on Tramp mode?

Tags: tramp

From my machine Windows 10, I connect to remote Linux machine by private like this (in console)

```
ssh -i d:\Remote\key\privatekey myLogin@some_remote_host
```

success connect:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-1026-gcp 
x86_64)
```

Nice.
Now I want by Tramp mode to connect:

```
C-x C-f 

/pscp:mylogin@ip_address:
```

But I get error:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you connect via ssh in the shell, you shall use ssh/scp also as Tramp connection method. Access the file as `/scp:mylogin@ip_address:`

The keyfile must be configured in `~/.ssh/config` (don't know what's the Windows equivalent) like

```
IdentityFile d:\Remote\QS\exchange\key\path_to_primary_key@ip_address
```

Comment: I copy private key to c:\Users\Alexei\.ssh\ , but it not help. Same error.

Comment: Well, I cannot say too much about Microsoft's ssh implementation. What I wrote was about GNU/Linux. Maybe you contact the documentation, whether there are different details compared to what I wrote.

Answer (score 3):

At least in my case I had to aad this to my `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host yourserverid2232323.amazonaws.com
    IdentityFile /home/justin/.ssh/aws-instance-1.pem
```

Now I can use Tramp like I would with my default ssh key.